# Generically Access functions of higher order function

Tags: reactjs

Say I have 2 components:

```js
class A extends Component {
  doSomething() {

  }
}

class B extends Component {
  doSomethingElse() {

  }
}
```

And I have an HOC:

```js
const hoc = Wrapped => {
  return class extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.wrapped.genericallyCallDosometingAndDsomethingElse()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapped ref={c => this.wrapped = c} {...this.props}/>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to call doSomething or doSomething else dependent on which component is passed in. Is there a better way than just calling the method the same thing in both components?

Answer (score 0):

You can have both functions for self documenting and general function for unified call:

```js
class A extends Component {
  doSomething() {
  }
  genericallyCallDosometingAndDsomethingElse() {
    this.doSomething()
  }
}

class B extends Component {
  doSomethingElse() {
  }
  genericallyCallDosometingAndDsomethingElse() {
    this.doSomethingElse()
  }
}
```

Also you can check the existence of function and call if exists:

```js
return class extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if( typeof this.wrapped.doSomething == 'function' )
      this.wrapped.doSomething();
    if( typeof this.wrapped.doSomethingElse == 'function' )
      this.wrapped.doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```